# Quasiconvexity (in the sense of Morrey) implies Rank-One convexity

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, calculus-of-variations

I am trying to understand why Quasiconvexity implies Rank-One convexity.

In a standard proof of this fact a sequence of functions is constructed, which converges weakly to zero in $W^{1,p}.$ in order to understand why this is useful, I would like to understand why my simpler argument is wrong.

Quasiconvexity of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{m\times d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ means that for any bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^d:$ $$\int_{\Omega}f(C + \nabla \omega(y))dy \ge | \Omega | f(C), $$ for any $\omega \in W_0^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$.

Now let us consider two matrices $A, B$ that are rank one connected, through $A-B = \xi \otimes \eta.$ Wlog we assume that $\eta = e_1 \in \mathbb{R^d}$ (else we rotate everything). We want to prove that $$f (\theta A + (1-\theta)B) \le \theta f(A) + (1-\theta) f(B)$$ So let us define $C = \theta A + (1-\theta)B$ and $ \Omega = (0,1)^d$ and $$ \omega(y) =  \begin{cases}
(1-\theta) (x \cdot e_1) \xi, \text{   if   } 0 \le x \cdot e_1 \le \theta \\ \\
-\theta (x \cdot e_1 -1) \xi, \text{   if   } \theta < x \cdot e_1 \le 1
\end{cases} $$ Now we find that the gradient of $\omega$ is: $$\nabla \omega (y) = \begin{cases}
(1-\theta)\xi \otimes e_1, \text{   if   } 0 \le x \cdot e_1 \le \theta \\ \\
-\theta \xi \otimes e_1, \text{   if   } \theta < x \cdot e_1 \le 1
\end{cases}$$ So eventually we find: $$\theta f(A) + (1-\theta) f(B) = \int_{\Omega}f(C + \nabla \omega(y))dy \ge f(C)$$ where the latter inequality holds by quasiconvexity.

A proof of this fact is given for example by Dacorogna in "Direct methods for calculus of variations," but it is actually more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is the natural first iteration of the argument. But it can't be the final form of the proof, because your function $\omega$ is not in $W^{1,\infty}_0(\Omega)$. It vanishes on two faces of the cube $(0,1)^d$ but not on the other faces.

One needs to multiply by a cutoff function $\eta$ to ensure zero boundary values of $\omega\eta$. Then of course $\nabla (\omega \eta) = \eta \nabla \omega + \omega \nabla \eta$, and one has to prevent the term with $\nabla \eta$ from messing up the inequality.

Comment: That was useful :D Thanks a lot!